# What do you call using another method when you can't explain something

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the method what you use when you know what to say but not exactly how to say it but use another method to do so?

You have an idea you have to explain to people, you know what you want to say but not how to *articulate* it correctly. So you end up using examples, sayings to help the person to understand what you are trying to convey, to help to get to the meat/jist of it until you get an "aha"moment that is what I'm trying to say

> The  stackexchange english language user knew what he wanted to ask in an indirect way but didn't know the exact words to ask it correctly so he used examples to trying get the question in a "*roundabout*" way.

or

> Pete wants directions to the arcade. He asks a passerby but forgot the word " arcade" so instead he asks "can you give me directions to the place in the mall where the 12-year old kids hang out?" He used  workaround way to explain where he wanted to go. He didn't say the correct word but the passerby knew the place he meant.

What method did Pete use?

> For the above Pete can't explain the word succinctly so he uses a [...] way or expresses it []

Words that don't fit exactly:

*convoluted means*. Convoluted means difficult to understand or complex where I'm trying to instead convey it's an "*other*"  way to ask to get there.

*non-succinct way* also is similar to the above

*Inarticulate method* coveys he isn't clear which is untrue since he is using another method

*parallel* conveys the two ways that are the same, where instead I want to say the the other method is instead an *out of the norm* way

*Roundabout*,*Workaround* is probably the closest I can think of

This might be a better explanation of the context

> The computer system user asks a question but the support ticket was closed with explanation "Your question is convoluted". The user believes the reason is unfair as he believed he question in isolation might be phrased without the correct technical terms but he additionally used a specific example to explain  what he was trying to achieve which left no room for ambiguity to understand what he was asking. He escalates it to their manager saying his question was not convoluted as he used used a [got to the jist of it] way to explain which the helpdesk should have understood and that he feels they were intentionally being *pedantic*.

Comment: [*Circumlocution*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/circumlocution), perhaps?

Comment: Mick, the definition says it means the same as roundabout. I am trying to say other way,  not necessary a long way just a different way. Almost like answering a question in another language.

Comment: Turn of phrase? - *a way of saying something:* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/turn-of-phrase

Comment: @JOSH that definition seem to a characteristic of a person where as I;m looking for a person uses it for a specific scenario where he for example forgets the word and uses another way to describe it.

Comment: Are you looking for a technical term, an idiomatic word or phrase, or just some plain English? For the last, I'd suggest *equivalent expression*. For the others, I've no idea.

Comment: technical or expression would be fine. Equivalent doesn't fit exactly as I am trying to convey he used an out of the norm way to explain e.g. the guy asking for directions. A word that means equivalent and different at the same time.

Comment: Are you using a _metaphor_ to try and explain an idea or situation?

Comment: If *circumlocution* doesn't fit because the right answer is "not necessarily a long way" I'm somewhat stymied that you've accepted *verbose* as the right answer. @Mick's suggestion is the exact term that experts in second language acquisition and traumatic brain injury use for this phenomenon. If you need an adjective, it would be *circumlocutory*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [paraphrase](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paraphrase) [MW]

> a restatement of a text, passage, or work giving the meaning in another form

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for ***verbose***.

ODO:

> **[verbose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verbose)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Using or expressed in more words than are needed.
>   ‘much academic
>   language is obscure and verbose’
>
> ‘Yesterday I told myself that I needed to stop teasing Kevin Keith
>   about his verbose comments.’
>   ‘I am sure that this email seems
>   overwhelming, and verbose.’
>   ‘She often wondered how could a man be
>   so verbose.’

Answer (score 1):

I actual thinking he's describing a parable [Wikipedia]

> A parable is a succinct, didactic story, in prose or verse, which illustrates one or more instructive lessons or principles.

For example, Jesus used the parable of the mustard seed to explain the joys that would be encountered in heaven from simple beginnings.

Answer (score 0):

*alternative* explaination? You rejected *convoluted* though it seems to apply to your example of looking for the arcade.

Comment: convoluted  dictionary meaning is "extremely complex and difficult to follow." If the computer user example he does the opposite making it easier to understand by providing an example for the helpdesk so there is no ambiguity. The user's lack of knowledge of technical terms doesn't mean his explanation was convoluted like was alleged by helpdesk. If you ask someone in the mall point me to the place in the mall where the kids hang out, there is nothing that indicates it is complex at all. A 5 year old could point you to where.

Answer (score 0):

How about *opaque*; which means unclear or not obvious.

It is also often used to explain speech or text, as in:

> "The manual was written using technical jargon that is opaque to many users."